# WPF Backgroundworking Thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, user-interface, backgroundworker

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Equivalent of DoEvent() in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14471254/equivalent-of-doevent-in-wpf)

i ask these question few days before but did not get much helpful comment as im totally new in WPF and no idea about threading however i have to deliver my task today and need to do these ASAP, 
Last time im using windows form and my function using DoEvent();
since im moved my program to WPF and do Event its not support anymore i need to convert these function

P.S: These function its to sending data to com port and Update UI

```
 private void Send(byte[] cmd)
        {
            bWaiting = true;
            MyResp = new byte[0];

            WriteOnPort(cmd);

            while (bWaiting == true) // here is a problem
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();  // here is a problem
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(15);
            }
        }
```

I really need to finish these by today and have no idea how to work it out any help would be great

Comment: Why are you waiting? are you waiting for `MyResp` to be populated in `WriteOnPort`??

Comment: What exactly is the problem where you say "here is a problem". Did you bother reading the links presented to you for your other question? Are you still looking for a WPF `DoEvents` even though it's really a bad idea? Did you look up the `Dispatcher`? I am not really sure what it is what exactly your question is...

Comment: Why you guys are so aggressive! if last question helped me i wouldn't post new one! @KenWhite you link me Article which is not useful and not solved my problem you think am i free to keep posting the same question if i solve it earlier! ( refer to my explanation that i explain earlier my last post wasnt help)

Comment: i dont need to use doEvent() im looking for backgroundworker to replace that function! whatever you guys told me last time its just not work

Comment: @sa_ddam213 yes i need to have so thread to update my UI after writing  otherwise my window will be freeze and i cant update UI or even stop process

Comment: @AlexanderaMacQueen: Because there are **rules** here you're supposed to follow, and you're not. Posting duplicates is a violation of this site's guidelines. If you didn't get help last time, you wrote the wrong question, and posting the same one again will not change that fact. I'm sorry you don't like the rules here, but you need to follow them just like everyone else. If you don't want to do that, this may not be the site for you.

Comment: If your question is about a `BackgroundWorker` then where is that code? Is this code in the `DoWork`? If the other code did not work then why did it not work? What _exactly_ was wrong with it? Asking the exact same question is not going to get you many different answers.

Answer (score 2):

An easy option would be to thread the `WriteOnPort` its way better than hacking a UI update.

Depending on what you need here are 2 examples

1. Simple thread method.

   ```
   private void Send(byte[] cmd)
   {
       ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) => WriteOnPort(cmd));
   }
   ```
2. using `BackroundWorker`, so you can use the `Completed` event when the `WriteOnPort` is complete

   ```
   private void Send(byte[] cmd)
   {
       var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
       worker.RunWorkerAsync(cmd);
       worker.DoWork += (s, e) =>
       {
          WriteOnPort(e.Argument as byte[]);
       };
       worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (cs, ce) =>
       {
          // do anything you need on completion
       };
   }
   ```

`System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()` is a horribl;e hack and should NEVER be used in this fashion in winforms, and tring to find a way to do the same hack in WPF is just silly, Have a play around with `Threading` and find the proper way to do things otherwise hacks like this will come back to haunt you one day.

Comment: you are right about DoEvent(0 i use it for temporary propose because i was thinking to migrate my code to WPF , i try your code but the program keep crash after running...

Comment: what is the error? can you add a try/catch and see the exception? I don't know all your code so its hard to tell whats causing the error

Answer (score -2):

```
public static void DoEvents()
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,                                        new Action(delegate { }));
}
```

Comment: oh my lord, this code is not going ito a production application is it?

Comment: This code it work! however its a poor method